# How can I derive the product distribution of two Meixner random variables?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have read these two Q&A:

[PDF of the product of two independent Gamma random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396324/pdf-of-the-product-of-two-independent-gamma-random-variables)

[How to Plot the PDF of Product of two Normals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92525/how-to-plot-the-pdf-of-product-of-two-normals)

I have two correlated Meixner random variables, $X$, and $Y$, where

$\qquad X\sim MXN(a=0.03306, b=0.30800, m=-0.00099, d=0.44168)$, 
$\qquad Y \sim MXN(a=0.03064, b=0.45599, m=-0.00173, d=0.51881)$

I need compute the product distribution the $Z=X \cdot Y$.  The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the Student's $t$ copula model with two parametrs: correlation $\rho=0.722$ and degree of freedom $v=7.566$.

I have tried

```
Z = 
  TransformedDistribution[x*y, 
    {x \[Distributed] MeixnerDistribution[0.03306, 0.30800, -0.00099, 0.44168], 
     y \[Distributed] MeixnerDistribution[0.03064, 0.45599, -0.00173, 0.51881]}]
```

and `TransformedDistribution` gives `Mean[Z]=2.50021*10^-6` output only.

**Edit**

I have tried `Plot[PDF[Z, x], {x, 0, 1}]` but the Mathematica software v.10 is running. I'm looking for the  theoretical solution.

**Question**

How to compute the product distribution of two Meixner variables?

Comment: Hmm, I believe the first parameter of `MeixnerDistribution[]` ought to be positive. Maybe check if the definition you're using matches *Mathematica*'s?

Comment: In support of @J.M.'s comment: [MeixnerDistribution >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeixnerDistribution.html): _MeixnerDistribution[a,b,m,d] allows m to be any real number, a and d to be any positive real number, and b such that -π <b<π._

Comment: @kglr, I have edited the order of arguments in MeixnerDistribution[].

Comment: Version 11.3 fails with PDF[Z, x].

Comment: Do you mean that you have two independent Meixner random variables rather than two correlated Meixner random variables?  I ask because you don't mention the correlation structure.  You also use $U$ and $V$ when I think you mean $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for comment. I added the information deal with the correlation structure.

Comment: Up to Wiki (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient ), the Kendall rank correlation coefficient is not it. The correlation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence ) is required.

Comment: It is impossible to find the  distribution of $X \cdot Y$ not knowing the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @user64494, I refreshed information about joint distribution.

Comment: Since you mention that you're using a $t$ copula, then the distribution you want is actually `TransformedDistribution[x y, {x, y} \[Distributed] CopulaDistribution[{"MultivariateT", {{1, 0.722}, {0.722, 1}}, 7.566}, {MeixnerDistribution[0.03306, 0.30800, -0.00099, 0.44168], MeixnerDistribution[0.03064, 0.45599, -0.00173, 0.51881]}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain an approximate plot of `PDF[Z, x]` in such a way.

```
Z = TransformedDistribution[x*y, {x \[Distributed]
MeixnerDistribution[0.03306, 0.30800, -0.00099, 0.44168], 
y \[Distributed] MeixnerDistribution[0.03064, 0.45599, -0.00173, 0.51881]}];
RandomVariate[Z, 10^4];Histogram[%, Automatic, "Probability"]
```

[image]

Addition. The answer which is valid for independent random variables was submitted before the edit of the question.

Comment: This is a good answer.  "The next best thing to having an explicit formula for the probability density function is having a gazillion random samples from that distribution."  (Are you going to modify to account for the OP's edit and maybe use `SmoothKernelDistribution` rather than a histogram?)